# Get the name of parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

The nested resources are defined in Rails:

```
resources :foo do
  resources :bar
end

resources :aaa do
  resources :bbb
end
```

I am trying to make application-wide layout with link to topmost resource, e.g. if user is somewhere in `bar` interface it will have handy link to `/foos/`.

And at the same time if the user is somethere in `bbb` the link will point to `/aaas`

So, the question is - in request to `bar` is any way to get the name of parent resource?

I know there is `foo_id` in `params`, but the problem is - I can't just get keys from `params` and hope that one of them with `_id` hint me to parent resource name.

Comment: There is now outdated sexy_nested_resources plugin, but looking at source I can't get - how can that plugin get the names.

Answer (score 1):

If you made sure that each nested model has a method called `parent` (or something similar), which returns the parent-object (obviously), then you could easily implement a `link_to_parent` in your `application_helper`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your suggest is a workaround. Source of that information is somewhere in routing layer and not in the models, the question is - how to get it from there.

Comment: True, it is a workaround. As far as i know this information is not passed on from the routing to the controller. You could investigate the `request_url`, but that feels more like a hack to me. It feels natural to me that a model knows it parent, so imho this is a good solution. But I'm always interested to hear better solutions.